# Django manage.py fails with "populate() isn't reentrant locally", but works on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, migration

I've got a bit of an odd problem with Django running correctly on remote, but failing locally. 
I'm developing a Django webapp and attempting to use makemigrations to add a few new fields to my models. Whenever I run makemigrations directly on Heroku, it functions correctly:

```
Migrations for 'users':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model CustomUser
    - Create model CorporateUser
    - Create model NormalUser
```

But obviously doesn't save. This is my first time using migrations: I recently migrated from Django 1.6.

I know I need to run makemigrations locally and push to remote, but whenever I try to use manage.py locally, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/bniii/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Users/bniii/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/Users/bniii/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/bniii/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

The one resource I could find on this specific question seemed to say that it's related to my installed apps, and so these are what I have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'users',  #my app

'django.contrib.sites',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
'bootstrapform',
)
```

If I comment out all the auth related apps, manage.py seems not to throw any errors, but with everything in place I always get this error. Does anyone know why this might be?